# write or delete keys in HKLM in XP,2000

Tags: delphi, registry

> How can delete keys on **HKLM** in windows **2000** or XP (before UAC)

it seems the program must run with admin rights but I don't find any correct ways .
this below codes are the delete procedure and it just work when I open the `regedit` and open that key , then program can delete keys .

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

var
  reg : TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_WRITE);
  //reg.Access := KEY_WRITE;
  reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

  reg.DeleteKey('SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Services\\OLD_DRIVER\\Enum');

  reg.CloseKey();

end;
```

Is there any other ways to delete the keys under HKLM like win32 API or run program with admin rights ?

> NOTE : this is not a duplicate question , it's a question after crawled all over the stackoverflow and not answered yet .

**EDIT & Notes** :
1. The OS is specially in Windows 2000 .
2. The addressed key at above code is a sub-key without any other sub-key .
3. Repeat it , **the above code will work if** I **Open** the **regedit** then go to `HKLM\\SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\Services\\OLD_DRIVER\\Enum` .
4. I've test it the registry create with `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` and `KEY_WRITE` and got the same result .
5. I've just testing it on 32 bit OS and not need `wow64 access` in registry create section .

Comment: What happens when you use `KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE`, or perhaps `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`? FWIW, it should be even easier in older Windows versions, because, as you said, UAC didn't exist yet. I don't have XP anymore, but that's what I first started with on Delphi. The issues started from Windows Vista and up.

Comment: @Graymatter that answer deals with UAC and WOW64, which don't apply in this situation (well, XP did support 64bit, but Windows 2000 certainly didn't).

Comment: Making modifications to `HKLM` always requires admin rights, you can't get around that. Also, if the requested key has any subkeys, you need to include the `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS` permission or else `DeleteKey()` will fail, as it needs to delete subkeys recursively before deleting the requested key. If you are using D2010 or later, `TRegistry` has `LastError` and `LastErrorMsg` properties to tell you why `DeleteKey()` (or any other method) fails. Also, do you really mean `SYSTEM_00` and not `SYSTEM`?

Comment: @JerryDodge , I've edit the question and add more details with notes , I've not tested the both `KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE` in create section yet and I'll let you know .

Comment: @RemyLebeau ,`1.` the key address is a last key (sub-key) and don't include any keys in sub , `2.` the parent directory in my other VM is `SYSTEM_00` and it's a test address so I've edit the question to `SYSTEM` like my main win2000 VM . I'll test my codes with `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS` too and let you know .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete a key with content (and subkeys) please try this code. It uses the [SHDeleteKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shdeletekeya) function which should be available in Windows 2000. Admin rights are usually required to delete keys in HKey_Local_Machine (members of the built in "Power Users" security group in Windows 2000 / XP can delete some, but not all).

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Windows;

function SHDeleteKey (hKey: HKEY; pszSubKey: LPCTSTR) : DWord; stdcall;
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
    external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyW';
{$ELSE}
    external 'shlwapi.dll' name 'SHDeleteKeyA';
{$ENDIF}

const
    cKey = 'SOFTWARE\Test';

begin
    if (SHDeleteKey (HKey_Local_Machine, cKey) = Error_Success) then
        WriteLn ('Success')
    else WriteLn ('Error');
end.
```